# Ansible win_scheduled_task how to start a task immediately

Tags: windows, ansible, autodesk

Help with advice please!

There is a program located in the path:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\AdskLicensing\Current\helper\AdskLicensingInstHelper.exe
```

And it must be run with the parameters:

```
register -pk 829L1 -pv 2020.0.0.F -cf "\\ srv\deploy$\RVT20\Img\x64\RVT\RevitConfig.pit" -el EN
```

I decided to do it through the task scheduler, but did not find in the documentation how to start the task immediately after it was added.

```
- name: recover ADSKLic Service
      win_scheduled_task:
        name: ADSK
        description: RecADSK
        actions:
        - path: 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\AdskLicensing\Current\helper\AdskLicensingInstHelper.exe'
          arguments: register -pk 829L1 -pv 2020.0.0.F -cf "\\srv\deploy$\RVT20\Img\x64\RVT\RevitConfig.pit" -el EN
        triggers:
        - type: registration
        frequency: once
        state: present
        enabled: yes
        username: SYSTEM
      tags: rev, adsk, task
```

The task is being added, but how to start it immediately after adding it?

It may of course be easier to run .exe via `win_command` or `raw`
but it doesn't work for me ...

Answer (score 5):

solved it myself .. it works.
task is added, immediately executed, and removed

```
 - name: recover ADSKLic Service Trough task scheduler
      win_scheduled_task:
        name: ADSK
        username: SYSTEM
        actions:
        - path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\AdskLicensing\Current\helper\AdskLicensingInstHelper.exe'
          arguments: register -pk 829L1 -pv 2020.0.0.F -cf "\\srv\deploy$\RVT20\Img\x64\RVT\RevitConfig.pit" -el EN
       # Remove this action if the task shouldn't be deleted on completion
        - path: cmd.exe
          arguments: /c schtasks.exe /Delete /TN "ADSK" /F
        triggers:
        - type: registration
      tags: task
    - name: Wait for the scheduled task to complete
      win_scheduled_task_stat:
        name: ADSK
        register: task_stat
        until: (task_stat.state is defined and task_stat.state.status != "TASK_STATE_RUNNING") or (task_stat.task_exists == False)
        retries: 7
        delay: 5
      tags: task
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I just wanted to say that the code as presented needs a slight tweak to work: in the `win_scheduled_task_stat:` section, only `name:` should be indented. `register:`, `until:`, `retries:` and `delay:` should be dedented (to be at the same level as `win_scheduled_task_stat:` and `tags:`), otherwise Ansible will complain.